# how to create standalone exe(without any dependencies) using UWP / Window forms / WPF that could run without .net framework?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

by using .net native (UWP application) i am able to build an app that could run without .net framework being installed but problem arises as it creates many dependencies(dll files) along with the app. i want to create a standalone application that could download a file(other exe) from web and execute it silently.

Comment: Here is a way to achieve that: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BrainstormingCreatingASmallSingleSelfcontainedExecutableOutOfANETCoreApplication.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Core 3, which is currently in preview, you can publish single-file executables using `dotnet` and the `PublishSingleFile` property:

```
dotnet publish -r win10-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

Please refer to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0-preview-5/) blog post for more information.

Comment: thanks for replying , actually i am looking to create a windows application(custom installer) that could install the files from web. in .net core3.0 can we create a window forms just like UWP/Window forms app ?

Comment: @LakshayBhardwaj: .NET Core supports both WPF and WinForms. If you want to create an installer, you should look into MSIX: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt833462